# How to dynamically change between profile pic and placeholder image

Tags: html, angular, typescript, firebase-storage, ionic4

Say you have a social media app with a profile pic that a user uploads to firebase from an Ionic app.  Once uploaded the placeholder icon should be dynamically changed to the actual profile pic the user just uploaded.  And if the user deletes that pic, then the placeholder image should return as the profile pic.

I need a little guidance on how to do this.  I'm not sure how to go about it although I know it should be easier than what I'm doing.

The problem with my current code is that the pic is only updated when the page is loaded.  So if a user uploads the pic they'll have to leave the page then reload it to see it as the profile pic.

How do I make this dynamic?  When a pic is uploaded it's immediately used as the profile pic.  And when it's deleted then the placeholder image is returned?

```js
  ionViewDidLoad() {
      this.loggedInUser = firebase.auth().currentUser; // code from firebase docs

      this.firestore.ref(`/Photos/${ this.userId }/`).child('photo0.png').getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
          this.cameraServiceProvider.photo0 = url;
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.message);
          this.cameraServiceProvider.photo0 = 'UseButton'
          console.log(this.cameraServiceProvider.photo0);
        });     
   }
```

```html
    <ion-card class="prflBg">
      <ion-card-content >
            <div [ngSwitch]="this.cameraServiceProvider.photo0">
                <div *ngSwitchDefault>
                    <img [src]="this.cameraServiceProvider.photo0" (click)="Present('photo0.png')"/>
                </div>
                <div *ngSwitchCase="'UseButton'">
                    <img src="assets/img/add-an-image.png" (click)="selectPhoto('photo0.png')"/>
                </div>      
            </div>
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have a getter for `[src]` of your image that returns the right source for each case. After you upload the image and get its source, you can run `changeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` to pick up the changes and recheck the view if you are using `OnPush` change detection strategy which you should absolutely do for the performance sake.

Comment: `changeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` shouldnt be needed, angular checks changes itself

Comment: @mast3rd3mon, It doesn't if you use `OnPush` which you totally should be doing.

Comment: i use whatever the default is and never have performance issues, `changeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` is something that you can use to accompany `ngzone.run` functions

Comment: Well, I can only say that I strongly recommend you to look into `OnPush`, not only it is better performance-wise — it also restricts some bad practices like mutability and improves your skills and quality of code. Besides steeper learning curve than `Default` strategy and some really edge cases, there is no reason not to use it.

Comment: ive never encountered any performance issues with angular, plus recommending something extra isnt what the OP asked for

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly, stating that this line of code is necessary for OnPush. If you are not open for this due to not being in a situation where these things matter, that's ok.

Comment: its not that im against it, its just that angular apps are very good on performance, changing how it detects changes will most likely negatively impact performance. and like i stated, the OP didnt ask for anything performance related, they asked how to make something dynamic